# Removing _embedded from a collection of REST resources

Tags: rest, spring-boot, spring-hateoas

Maybe this goes against REST/HAL principles but I thought that if I was viewing a list of items they should not be contained in an `_embedded` tag. Below is the details returned when I navigate to `/characters` in my spring boot application.

I had expected `_embedded` to not be present for the `characterDescriptions` since they are the main focus of the page, is it possible to achieve this? Should I try to achieve this or would `_embedded` be the norm here?

On a related note when I navigate to a particular resource using the link ( like `characters/1` for instance) should I be linking back to the `/characters` parent page or is it acceptable to only contain a self-link at these kinds of endpoints (I will be eventually linking to the user here but this is a general question about REST endpoints )

The controller method that returns this JSON is below the JSON

```
{
    "_embedded": {
        "characterDescriptions": [
            {
                "characterName": "Adrak",
                "playerName": "Liam",
                "userName": "liam",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/characters/1"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "characterName": "Thorny",
                "playerName": "Aedo",
                "userName": "aedo",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/characters/2"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "characterName": "Anin",
                "playerName": "Saoirse",
                "userName": "saoirse",
                "_links": {
                    "self": {
                        "href": "http://localhost:8080/characters/3"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    "_links": {
        "self": {
            "href": "http://localhost:8080/characters"
        }
    }
}
```

Here's the relevant method

```
    @GetMapping
    public ResponseEntity<Resources<Resource<CharacterDescription>>> getAllCharacterDescriptions( ) {

        List <Resource<CharacterDescription>> characters = repository.findAll()
                .stream().map( character -> {
                    Link characterLink = linkTo(methodOn(CharacterDescriptionController.class)
                            .getCharacterDescription(character.getCharacterId()))
                            .withSelfRel();
                    return new Resource<>(character, characterLink);
                }).collect(Collectors.toList());

        Link allCharacterLink = linkTo(methodOn(CharacterDescriptionController.class)
                                        .getAllCharacterDescriptions(auth))
                                        .withSelfRel();

        Resources<Resource<CharacterDescription>> resources = new Resources<>(characters, allCharacterLink);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(resources);
    }
```

Comment: You could try to annotate the embedded resources with [@JsonUnwrapped](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.0.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonUnwrapped.html) similar to [an example](https://github.com/opencredo/spring-hateoas-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/opencredo/demo/hateoas/api/resources/ResourceWithEmbeddeds.java#L11) which defines its own embedded resource support class

Comment: No luck still shows as _embedded

Comment: Here page is considered as a resource itself,  that is why `characterDescriptions` are under `_embeded`

Answer (score 0):

According to [the HAL spec](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-kelly-json-hal-07#section-4.1.2) you can either render a single resource, with its content and set of links, or you can render an aggregate resource, which has room for multiple resources-within-this-resource.

In your domain model, you clearly show multiple documents, each with a distinct `self` URI (`/characters/1`, `/characters/2`, etc.), hence, you aren't serving up a single item resource, but instead an aggregate root.

If you read the HAL spec, you'll find this definition underneath `_embedded`:

> It is an object whose property names are link relation types (as defined by RFC5988) and values are either a Resource Object or ***an array of Resource Objects***.

In fact, looking for the word **array** in the HAL spec, only leads you to section quoted above, and the `_links` section.

Hence, `_embedded` is the proper place to render an array of resources in HAL.